# Retrieve data from multiple excel file by using file path in the cell value

Tags: excel, excel-2010, export-to-excel, vba

I have a excel file and I wish to auto retrieve all data by just clicking a button.

I have stored the file path in B11 to B13.

My code is as below:

```
Sub FetchData()

Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim shSource As Worksheet
Dim shDestin As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Corporate Quality\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")
Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
Set shSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set shDestin = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
shDestin.Range("E11") = shSource.Range("A2")
wbSource.Close False
End Sub
```

Is there possible to change the `Workbooks.Open Filename:= "C:\Users\Corporate Quality\Desktop\test\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet"` to B11:B13 ?

Comment: Yes. As what @AndyG posted, you can concatenate it the same way. If however you want to load all info from different file sources stored in B11-B13, you will have to loop through it and revise your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's in B11:B13 but you can concatenate the values in the same way as you are already doing for B3. For example,

```
Filename := Range("B11").Value & Range("B12").Value & Range("B13").Value
```